# как освободить память с помощью free()

Tags: c++, массивы, указатели, память, структуры

В классе создается структура и указатель на нее.
В конструкторе для структуры выделяется нужная память.
После использования класса нужно освободить память, выделенную для структуры.
Для операций с памятью используются `malloc()` и `free()`.
Как правильно освободить память, выделенную для структуры?

Создается класс:

```
class SUSLIK
{
    struct Data 
    {
        int maxInt;         
        double* matrix;     
    };

    struct Data *pData;
public:
    SUSLIK(int max);
    ~SUSLIK();

};
```

В конструкторе выделяется память для структуры:

```
SUSLIK::SUSLIK(int max)
{
    pData = (Data *)malloc(sizeof(Data)); // memory allocation
    pData->matrix = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double) * (max + 2) * (max + 2));
}
```

Теперь нужно в деструкторе освободить память, выделенную для структуры.
Как это правильно сделать, используя функцию free() ?

```
if (pData) free(pData->matrix); // это не работает
```

Comment: проверяете указатель pData, а память освобождаете у pFitData. Странно. С другой стороны - нужно просто позвать free  в противоположном порядке от malloc

Comment: Почему вы используете `malloc/free`, а не `new/delete`?

Comment: free(pData) тоже нужно _ освободив память на которую указывает член и освободить память выделенная для объекта

Comment: @ARHovsepyan - внутри структуры есть указатель, который указывает на массив динамически выделенной памяти. Сначала нужно освободить эту память. Варианты типа free(pData) не работают

Comment: Подробнее выложите код, ошибка где-то происходит. Может-быть даже не из-за этого класса. По этому происходит неопределённое поведение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы же работаете с С++ - используйте его идиоматику...

```
class SUSLIK
{
    struct Data 
    {
        int maxInt;         
        double* matrix;
        Data(int max):matrix(new double[(max+2)*(max+2)]){}
        ~Data() { delete[] matrix; }
    };

    Data *pData;
public:
    SUSLIK(int max):pData(new Data(max)){}
    ~SUSLIK(){ delete pData; }

};
```

Каждый отвечает за себя :)

Если вы позарез хотите писать на С++, как на С - ну, что-то вроде

```
class SUSLIK
{
    struct Data 
    {
        int maxInt;         
        double* matrix;
    };

    Data *pData;
public:
    SUSLIK(int max)
    {
        pData = (Data *)malloc(sizeof(Data)); // memory allocation
        pData->matrix = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double) * (max + 2) * (max + 2));
    }
    ~SUSLIK()
    {
        free(pData->matrix);
        free(pData);
    }
};
```

Comment: Все зашибись, только появляется ошибка "Исключение не обработано" на строчке ~Data() { delete[] matrix; }

Comment: Все зашибись, только хрен его знает, как вы его используете. Вы же код не приводите - не мое, наверное, собачье дело, сколько ошибок вы накрутили вокруг... https://ideone.com/3qhmU3

Comment: Ну зачем вы так :) В женщине должна быть тайна :) Вот она и не хочет показывать свой код, чтобы остаться загадкой :)

Comment: @Mikhailo Да надоело - ваш код не работает! - а потом выясняется, что человек сам глупость написал... Словом, манеру выставлять вопросы/претензии без кода я считаю просто некорректным.

Answer (score 0):

Выделение памяти под массив может оказаться не удачным, поскольку квадрат числа может оказаться слишком большим числом(да и само переданное число), и в памяти может не быть столько свободного места для такого массива. В этом случаи будет выброшено исключение, указатель останется нулевым, а освобождение нулевой  памяти, невозможным.  Поэтому нужно это проверить и уменьшить размер до тех пор, пока память не будет выделена. На С++ код может выглядеть следующим образом:

```
class SUSLIK
{
    struct Data
    {
        int maxInt{};
        double* matrix{ nullptr };       
    } *pData;
public:
    SUSLIK(int max) : pData(new Data)
    {        
        size_t N = (max + 2) * (max + 2);
        while (pData->matrix == nullptr) {
            try {
                pData->matrix = new double[N];
            }
            catch (std::bad_alloc&) {
                N /= 2;
            }
        }
    } 
    ~SUSLIK()
    {
        delete[]pData->matrix;
        delete pData;
    }
};
```

Comment: "а освобождение нулевой памяти невозможным" - точно? delete и free умеют корректно с nullptr работать

Comment: @KoVadim , а я не говорил, что освобождение нулевой памяти является ошибкой, просто невозможно удалять то, чего нет...И невозможность еще будет связана с тем, что будет выброшено исключение, и объект не создастся.

Comment: тогда непонятна реплика совсем.

Comment: может быть, но я выразился как мог.

Comment: А какой смысл в выделении меньшего количества памяти, чем нужно? Логично просто сгенерировать исключение (оно само сгенерируется), а не пытаться выделить меньше памяти, чем нужно.